# How to use cache with Google Sheets in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-sheets-api, spring-cache

I am just starting to learn Spring Boot and am trying to use cache with the Google Sheets API to study Springboot. To use cache with Google Sheets in Spring Boot, I added the spring-boot-starter-cache dependency in my pom.xml file and enabled cache support by using the @EnableCaching annotation in my application's main class. I then used the @Cacheable annotation for caching the response from the Google Sheets API when calling a method to get a spreadsheet. However, the cache does not work, as the method is still being called every time.

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class GoogleSheetsService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleSheetsService.class);

    @Cacheable(value = "spreadsheet", key = "#spreadsheetId")
    public Spreadsheet getSpreadsheet(String spreadsheetId) {
        logger.info("Getting spreadsheet from API for {}", spreadsheetId);
        // Call Google Sheets API to get spreadsheet
        return spreadsheet;
    }
}
```

I expected the cache to return the cached value for the same spreadsheetId, but the method is being called every time and the "Getting spreadsheet from API for {}" log is being printed. Can you please help me understand what might be causing the cache to not work as expected?

Comment: Are you injecting GoogleSheetsService or manually constructing it? Because since caching is taken care of by spring using aspects, the service needs to be injected (using either constructor injection or Autowired annotation) for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can doubt two things.

1. Are other methods of Google Sheets Service calling the spreadsheet method?

`@Cacheable` uses the AOP concept of Spring Framework.
So it doesn't apply to calling other methods in the same class.

2. Have you registered the spreadsheet with CacheManager?

With Java Config, it is as follows,

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

  @Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    ConcurrentMapCacheManager mgr = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
    mgr.setCacheNames(asList("employees"));
    return mgr;
  }
}
```

[link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-cache-example/)

Is the spreadsheet registered with cacheManager?